# BobMgr::GetBuf: Sort Big Output Buffer write not complete after 60 seconds

Tags: sql-server

One of our production servers showing below error msg in Sql Server Log from last week,

> SQL Server has encountered 20674 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [D:\Databasefile.mdf] in database [Database] (11). The OS file handle is 0x0000000000000828. The offset of the latest long I/O is: 0x00001c3bde0000
>   and today in addition to the above one more msg,
>
> BobMgr::GetBuf: Sort Big Output Buffer write not complete after 60 seconds.

is this the indication of a serious issue? How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

> BobMgr::GetBuf: Sort Big Output Buffer write not complete after 60 seconds.

Big Output Buffers (BoBs) are used when a sort spills to *tempdb*.

The 'big' buffer optimizes for large sequential I/O instead of writing sort records individually.

A delay of this length indicates a problem with the disk subsystem.